React-Native Expo can't save key and value data in localStorage
I have a difficult case for me to solve, in my case I want to setItem to localStorage using
npm i @react-native-async-storage/async-storage "1.23.1"
but when I open DevTools using "J" in keyboard terminal in Application -> Local Storage there is no value and key set as if nothing happened but I checked with console value and key has been set but not saved in localStorage.

and this my code I use
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Modal,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
} from "react-native";
import { ThemedView } from "@/components/ThemedView";
import { ThemedText } from "@/components/ThemedText";
import { ThemedButton } from "@/components/ThemedBtn";
import { ParamListBase, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { NativeStackNavigationProp } from "react-native-screens/lib/typescript/native-stack/types";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const TermsAndPolicy = () => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(true);
  const navigation = useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<ParamListBase>>();

  const handleAgree = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('hasTermsAndPolicy', 'true');
      setModalVisible(false);
      navigation.navigate("OnboardingPage/OnboardingPage");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to save the Terms and Policy status:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ThemedView>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(false);
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <ThemedView style={styles.modalView}>
            <SafeAreaView>
              <ScrollView>
                <ThemedView style={styles.textTherms}>
                  <ThemedText type="title">Terms and Policy 1</ThemedText>
                  <ThemedText type="default">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Dolores cum asperiores facilis sapiente suscipit,
                    accusantium ea, ipsam, at sint neque veniam omnis
                    reprehenderit dolorem excepturi inventore rem. Vero maiores,
                    possimus inventore perspiciatis quaerat earum exercitationem
                    accusamus beatae dignissimos. Doloremque aut eligendi
                    quibusdam deleniti et voluptatum similique repellat
                    consequatur voluptate aliquid.
                  </ThemedText>
                </ThemedView>
                <ThemedView style={styles.textTherms}>
                  <ThemedText type="title">Terms and Policy 1</ThemedText>
                  <ThemedText type="default">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Dolores cum asperiores facilis sapiente suscipit,
                    accusantium ea, ipsam, at sint neque veniam omnis
                    reprehenderit dolorem excepturi inventore rem. 
                  </ThemedText>
                </ThemedView>
                <ThemedView style={styles.textTherms}>
                  <ThemedText type="title">Terms and Policy 3</ThemedText>
                  <ThemedText type="default">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Dolores cum asperiores facilis sapiente suscipit,
                    accusantium ea, ipsam, at sint neque veniam omnis
                    reprehenderit dolorem excepturi inventore rem. 
                  </ThemedText>
                </ThemedView>
                <ThemedView style={styles.footer}>
                  <ThemedButton title="Lanjutkan" onPress={handleAgree} />
                </ThemedView>
              </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
          </ThemedView>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </ThemedView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  centeredView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  modalView: {
    padding: 10,
    margin: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
    height: 600,
  },
  textTherms: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  footer: {
    alignItems: "flex-start",
  },
});

export default TermsAndPolicy;


Is the code I wrote correct?

Data gets saved in local storage but not shown in devtools.
You are right to clean your app caches.
    const handleAgree = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('hasTermsAndPolicy', 'true');
      setModalVisible(false);
      navigation.navigate("OnboardingPage/OnboardingPage");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to save the Terms and Policy status:", error);
    }
  };

